# String JSON docs in Aurora Postgress vs Aurora Mysql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I need to store JSON file into RDS.

We have tried in My SQL but filtering based on JSON field or displaying JSON field from Mysql is not working.

Before moving to NOSQL which is turning out to be very costly for us wanted to check if Postgres is can handle this with good performance.

so for example lets say we have below value in table

```
id |  name  | age |                     more_info                    
----+--------+-----+---------------------------------------------------
  1 | Thomas |  22 | {"email": "thom22@gmail.com", "country": "US"}
  2 | Jerry  |  24 | {"email": "jerrybac@gmail.com", "country": "UK"}
  3 | Annie  |  21 | {"email": "anniehan@ymail.com", "country": "AUS"}
```

If we want to query id,name,age,more_info.country is it possible?
Can we index more_info in the this table?

based on expert experience is it advisable to use Postgres for JSON.
We do have two columns which will be an jsonb type.

Number of records are more in this table more than 2 Billions .

Comment: Why not use a properly normalized table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is just an example but we have json file which is more than 100 KB some time and also the nodes in json is not same so normalizing this into many columns or generic columns will be very difficult .One more thing we are already using this in our application so do not want to change full system/aap for now

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we have looked at Dynamo db and Document db which support JSON filtering so if we have chose Dynamo vs Document vs Postgress which one would be better .Dyanamo for us costs 4 times more than RDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for a specific country in different ways, and they will require different indexes to speed up the search (I am assuming that the column is define as `jsonb`)

You can create a GIN index on the whole JSON value:

```
create index on the_table using gin(more_info jsonb_path_ops);
```

The above index can support the contains operator `@>`

So the following queries could make use of that index:

```
select *
from the_table
where more_info @> '{"country": "AUS"}'

select *
from the_table
where more_info @> '{"email": "thom22@gmail.com"}'
```

Alternatively using the operator class `jsonb_ops` can be used which [supports](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) more operators, but is a bit slower.

GIN indexes are a bit bigger and slower to maintain compared to B-Tree indexes. If you know the specific keys you want to query, a B-Tree index on that key might be more efficient:

```
create index on the_table using gin( (more_info ->> 'country') );
```

That index can be used by the following query:

```
select *
from the_table
where more_info ->> 'country' = "AUS";
```

Note that this approach requires one index per key you want to query on. Whereas the GIN index can support any query that uses the `@>`.

As the GIN index is a "multi-purpose" index supporting a wide range of expressions, it might not be as efficient and fast as dedicated B-Tree indexes. You will need to experiment with your data and queries to see which performs better.

Comment: Great so we can start POC on postgress to evaluate this i guess this feature is not supported in Mysql .